# $f(x)>0,\,\,\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=+\infty \implies \lim_{t\to b^-}\int_{t_0}^{t}f(x)\,dx=+\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions, special-functions

Let $(a,b)\subset \Bbb{R}$ be an interval and $f:(a,b)\to \Bbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Suppose that $f(x)>0$, $\forall x\in (a,b)$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=+\infty$. Let $t_0\in (a,b)$ be fixed. Is it possible that
$$\int_{t_0}^bf(x)\,dx:=\lim_{t\to b^-}\int_{t_0}^{t}f(x)\,dx<+\infty?$$

Is there any example of this? Under which conditions on $f$ this happens or not?

Comment: Think of the arcsin integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$ This behavior is quite common and leads to a type of *improper* Riemann integrals where the interval of integration is bounded but the function itself is unbounded on that interval.

Comment: However there is no such example when $b=\infty$ and then the implication in your title of question is true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:
$$
f(x) = |x|^{-1/2}, \qquad \lim_{x\to0^{-}} |x|^{-1/2}=+\infty,
$$
while
$$
\int_{-1}^0 |x|^{-1/2} \,dx = 2.
$$

Under what conditions does this happen?

For the following particular family of functions, 
$$
f(x) = |x|^{-a}, \qquad a>0,
$$
the integral is finite when $a<1$, while the integral does not exist $(\infty)$ when $a\ge 1$.